# How to return the result from Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following methods:

```
public int getData() { return 2; } // suppose it is slow and takes 20 sec

// pseudocode
public int GetPreviousData()
{
    Task<int> t = new Task<int>(() => getData());
    return _cachedData; // some previous value
    _cachedData = t.Result; // _cachedData == 2
}
```

I don't want to wait for the result of an already running operation.

I want to return `_cachedData` and update it after the `Task` will finish.

How to do this? I'm using `.net framework 4.5.2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to use an `out` parameter here:

```
public Task<int> GetPreviousDataAsync(out int cachedData)
{
    Task<int> t = Task.Run(() => getData());
    cachedData = _cachedData; // some previous value
    return t; // _cachedData == 2
}

int cachedData;
cachedData = await GetPreviousDataAsync(out int cachedData);
```

Pay attention to the `Task.Run` thing: this starts a task using the thread pool and returns a `Task<int>` to let the caller decide if it should be awaited, continued or *fire and forget* it.

See the following sample. I've re-arranged everything into a class:

```
class A
{
    private int _cachedData;
    private readonly static AutoResetEvent _getDataResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    private int GetData()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public Task<int> GetPreviousDataAsync(out int cachedData)
    {
        // This will force calls to this method to be executed one by one, avoiding
        // N calls to his method update _cachedData class field in an unpredictable way
        // It will try to get a lock in 6 seconds. If it goes beyong 6 seconds it means that 
        // the task is taking too much time. This will prevent a deadlock
        if (!_getDataResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Some previous operation is taking too much time");
        }

        // It has acquired an exclusive lock since WaitOne returned true

        Task<int> getDataTask = Task.Run(() => GetData());
        cachedData = _cachedData; // some previous value

        // Once the getDataTask has finished, this will set the 
        // _cachedData class field. Since it's an asynchronous 
        // continuation, the return statement will be hit before the
        // task ends, letting the caller await for the asynchronous
        // operation, while the method was able to output 
        // previous _cachedData using the "out" parameter.
        getDataTask.ContinueWith
        (
            t =>
            {
                if (t.IsCompleted)
                    _cachedData = t.Result;

                // Open the door again to let other calls proceed
                _getDataResetEvent.Set();
            }
        );

        return getDataTask;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        int previousCachedData;
        // Don't await it, when the underlying task ends, sets
        // _cachedData already. This is like saying "fire and forget it"
        GetPreviousDataAsync(out previousCachedData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to return a previous cached data, but you return the `Task`.

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko you need to study Task Asynchronous Pattern. Look on the net for info about this concept. BTW, check my updated answer.

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko I believe that my answer is a good start for you to upgrade your .NET knowledge and skills. Why don't you take your time to understand what`s a `Task`, what's async-await, an `out` parameter? It's just my advise.

Comment: Actually, upon further inspection, there are more issues: calling `Task.Run` on a `Task<int>` instance, misuse of `Interlocked.Exchange` (it doesn't protect anything in this case, you're setting a reference, which is an atomic operation on all systems, following a memory barrier inserted by `await`) - possibly other things too.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I'm fixing this... The interlocked thing, also, it's oriented to tell the OP investigate further about thread synchronization

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy In addition, OP was saying "I'm using .NET 4.5.2" (like a justification of "it won't work this way (using tasks)" as comments in other answers. I mean, it's clear OP needs to study these concepts.

Comment: Understood. I'm guilty of the same sometimes. Hoping to see a high quality answer when you finish editing.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Done... Let's see if this is fine for you

Comment: What happens if they get 20 requests for the data at once...will it send off 20 tasks to fetch it?

Comment: @TimB Does this requirement goes out of the scope of this Q&A? I mean, we can solve a lot of issues. What happens if other class members use _cachedData and the whole class isn't thread-safe.... I believe that OP should go step by step and solve things also step by step. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @TimB If you find extremely useful that I add this protection, I can add it anyway...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I think it's important in this case as it would have bad consequences if it didn't. Personally I would put a note in the answer saying that you need to consider that case and the case of thread safety along with a pointer in the right direction to fix them...whether you want to do more or less than that is up to you though :)

Comment: @TimB Oops, I thought you asked me to do so, hahaha, it was the OP. Well, the effort was near to zero

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko I've added it. BTW, from now, you need to improve the sample code yourself ;)

Comment: @TimB Well, actually I should use a reset event or something like that, the lock won't prevent the whole scenario of 20 tasks fetching data...

Comment: Yeah. TBH this isn't how I'd architect it but I don't know C# well enough to write a full answer with code. Basically I'd return an int which is either the cached value or the queried value. Task would start at null. If task is null create new task and return cached value. If task is not null return cached value. When task completes reset it to null. No need to return the Task at all, that's an implementation detail that should be hidden away from the caller. First time the method is called it would need to wait for a return so the initial value is valid.

Comment: @TimB Well, returning a `Task` is a good idea, because the caller can decide if it needs to await the underlying task to finish or not. It's up to the caller decide if the call is awaited or you want it nearly as a "fire and forget" operation. Maybe some caller needs to do something once the data retrieval has ended...

Comment: For sure, it depends on the use case. Unless there is a specific need to reveal the task it's better to hide it though. You can always add an `lastUpdateTime` or similar on the object though to allow this without exposing the internal workings.

Comment: @TimB It's the idea behind task asynchronous pattern... It's like always encapsulating class fields with properties. Sometimes you can find yourself saying "why? I'm not going to need any variation on how I get a value from a field", but you still encapsulate them with properties because you never know what you need in the future. The point of returning the task has the same reasoning: why not? It's worth the effort and your code is more generalist.

Comment: @TimB Actually it's not what TAP enforces. Return the task, and upper layers will decide what to do. You're just exposing "I'm going to end in a while" and a result. Obviously, if you want to encapsulate a result but still follow TAP, you can use `Task.FromResult` or `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`. Do you know them?

Comment: Until in the future you change your implementation in some way that means you are no longer using a `Task` for whatever reason. This conversation is getting too long though :) It's a good answer either way.

Comment: @TimB Thanks ;) Then, the answer to your concern is **refactor or die**. I mean, you can't leave a code *as is* for years: you need to evaluate the code base overtime and refactor it as soon as you find some design flaw

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the cached value in your class, and then when the value is queried check whether you're already updating it. If you are just return the cached value. If not then launch a new query and return the cached value.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to wait at all for the task to finish, you can have the function start the task and handle the setting in a `ContinueWith`

```
    public int GetPreviousData()
    {
        Task.Run((Func<int>)getData).ContinueWith(t => _cachedData = t.Result);            
        return _cachedData; // some previous value
    }
```

If race conditions are an issue, you can assign `_cachedData` to a variable first, then run the task and immediately return the variable, but if getData takes any time at all, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Why using explicit continuations when we've `async`-`await`

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko you're stuck in .net 3.5 in your mind :D What has to do .NET 4.5.2 with this answer? TAP/TPL is available since .NET 4.0 (2009?)

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko maybe you've your own C# compiler, because `Task<int>` will always have a `Result` property :(

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer : about the explicit continuation: because awaiting is not needed, even not wanted in this case. simply fire and forget, so the function returns the previous value immediately (for whatever design reason) Sure, an awaitable setter could be called inside an extra task within GetPreviousData, but wouldn't do much for readability (although might be better if the waiting is IO bound)

Comment: This does seem to be the better answer as the OP doesn't seem to care about races, and all requirements are met. You could even shorten your task to `Task.Run(() => _cachedData = getData())` (the continuation doesn't give you anything as you aren't specifying the scheduler), and maintain near-identical behaviour with improved readability. Obviously there's the issue of error handling (in .NET 4 you would get the ghastly `UnobservedTaskException` if `getData` fails; in later versions just a silent failure), but this seems outside the scope of the question.